# Get layout from button

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In a Xamarin forms project I am trying to get a StackLayout from a button clicked event. The StackLayout can have 1-3 buttons when one is clicked it calls

```
static void PollButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        button.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

But I need to be able to disable all of the buttons. I tried looking for something like button.GetLayout so I could loop through the Children to find all the buttons but haven't found any methods for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Parent` property of the `Element`, and then loop through the `Children` of that `Element` skipping the `Button` that is the sender if need be.

Example:

```
void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var child in ((sender as Button).Parent as StackLayout).Children)
    {
        if (child is Button && !child.Equals(sender))
        {
            child.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!

Comment: @Daniel No problem, glad to help 